# Remotely execute Software Center Package using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, installation, sccm

I have a specific use case where I need to remotely execute the Windows 10 version 1809 OS upgrade package which is published in Software Center under the Operating Systems tab on a Windows 10 v1709 PC. I have a PowerShell one-liner that will do it remotely when the PC is logged in with an admin account (the same account that the PC is logged in with) as shown below:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Computer001 {(New-Object -ComObject "UIResource.UIResourceMgr").ExecuteProgram("*", "OS_UpGrade", $true)}
```

That works perfectly when the target PC is logged in with the same account that I have used to run PowerShell terminal with. But when the PC (Computer001) is logged off, and I run the same command, I get this error:

```
"Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
+ CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
+ PSComputerName        : Computer001"
```

I am guessing that the ComObject cannot be called when the PC is logged off, is that correct and is there any way around that?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: But if I can read the package when the PC is logged off (icm -computername computer001 {(New-Object -ComObject "UIResource.UIResourceMgr").GetAvailableApplications() | ?{ $_.PackageId -eq "MyPackage"}} | select PackageId, FullName - then surely I should be able to execute it?

Comment: There are many things you can do to / get from a host system,  whether anyone is logged on or not. There are specific things that require the interaction of a logged-on user. Anything that requires a logged-on user, you cannot do with PowerShell, as this is a Windows security boundary that PowerShell by default will not do this. If you need to run code as the logged-on user, then you need to leverage say, psexec.exe. Any UI actions require a logged-on user. Any remote install must be done either via GPO or scheduled task ran with the right creds.

Answer (score 0):

I took a deeper look at the documentation here.

The issue is specifically the COM object you are calling (as you expected).

The SDK for SCCM specifically mentions this COM object is the UI for CM. UIResource.UIResourceMgr. It also notes in the SDK that this particular object can be difficult to call *because* it relies on user context.

I'm afraid you are going to have to find an execution that does not rely on calling the UI Resource.

It may be easier to run this via PSExec than a PowerShell script invoking SCCM as I presume you cannot use SCCM itself to invoke the installation remotely.

Comment: Thanks for your input guys, I have resorted to SCCM manditory ADGroups.